# How can you assign a class to an id in css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now, every text box I make looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="disableHotkeys">
```

Elsewhere, I have code that disables hot keys whenever an element of class "disableHotkeys" is focused on, and enables when all are blurred.

This all works fine, but I'd rather input elements were of class "disableHotkeys" by default as to clean up the code, and be less repetitive.

What I want is something like this:

```
default.css:

//don't use this code
input
{  include .disableHotkeys;  }
```

Is there a way of doing this in the css?

If not, I imagine there is a way to add the class to everything with JQuery after page load, but it seems like bad form to set the class outside of the places developers would usually look (the html/php file, and maybe the css).

P.S. if you have a better title, it would be appreciated

Comment: can you make your question more precise?

Comment: Try Jquery addclass http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Why aren't you adding the class at the server? No script required.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I think that was what I had been doing.  It worked, but it led to a lot of copying and pasting, which generally means I'm doing something wrong.  Also, the way I have it now, I don't have to worry about accidentally leaving a textbox in a mode that will trigger hotkeys when typed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, with CSS only, you're not able to do it. You need to use JS. I am giving you a jQuery example -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').addClass('disableHotkeys');
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('disableHotkeys');
    });
});
```

And also if you need to add class to all input then why dont put disableHotkeys class code to input?

Comment: The reason I wasn't putting it to input was I didn't know I could.  I'll probably be doing that, but for now I'm just making sure this question get's the most appropriate answer.  Is there any difference between the two functions you've shown?

Comment: in each function you can make exception/complex conditional based action, if you want to else no need. First one will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a class to all the text inputs on DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ":text" ).addClass("yourclassname");

});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/8Sm9d/) fiddle.

Comment: This looks perfect.  Out of interest, where would something like this conventionally be placed to make it obvious to developers where the class assignment is coming from?